# Creating symbolic link

Tags: linux, centos, symlink

I've just picked up a new client's server, he's running CentOS. The server hosts a web app. There are currently two discs on the server, a 120GB SSD disc and a 2TB HDD disc.

The original developer has placed the web app inside the SSD partition, this partition is being spammed by cache files being generated everytime a user uploads some content (images/videos).

I don't want to move the app over to the HDD drive at this time of year (1 week until christmas). So I want to symlink this cache directory on the SSD over to the HDD.

Let's say the cache folder resides in the following folder:

```
// This is inside the SSD partition
/home/app/var/cache
```

I want to symlink the cache folder over to the HDD partition so that the cache files are being stored on the HDD partition. Let's say the folder I want to move the files over to is below:

```
/mnt/new_cache_folder
```

The server is very fragile IMO - No back-ups, the guys web app has been installed 3-4 times on the SSD disc  (in different places), so I am taking a cautious approach to this. I don't want to cause myself a christmas headache!

Any advice on how to do this with CentOS would be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move everything from `/home/app/var/cache` to the new directory, then create the symlink :

```
$ mv /home/app/var/cache /mnt/new_cache_folder
$ ln -s /mnt/new_cache_folder /home/app/var/cache
```